# No data display in jspx

Tags: java, jsp, jspx

I have an application which should display data about singers, taken from MySQL datbase. However, when I launch the app and open my browser I see nothing but ${singer.firstName}, ${singer.lastName}, ${singer.birthDate}. Changing isELIgnored to false, which was recommended by other stackoverflow users, did not help. JSPX page looks like this

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <spring:message code="label_singer_list" var="labelSingerList"/>
    <spring:message code="label_singer_first_name" var="labelSingerFirstName"/>
    <spring:message code="label_singer_last_name" var="labelSingerLastName"/>
    <spring:message code="label_singer_birth_date" var="labelSingerBirthDate"/>

    <html>
    <head><title>Title</title></head>
    <body>
    <h1>${labelSingerList}</h1>
    <c:if test="${not empty singers}">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>${labelSingerFirstName}</th>
                <th>${labelSingerLastName}</th>
                <th>${labelSingerBirthDate}</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${singers}" var="singer">
                <tr>
                    <td>${singer.firstName}</td>
                    <td>${singer.lastName}</td>
                    <td>${singer.birthDate}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </c:if>
    </body>
    </html>
</jsp:root>
```

Message codes are for internationalization. Since I already tested the app without them, they don`t affect results I get.

EDIT:
I`ve changed the content of my jspx page according to http://www.hs-augsburg.de/homes/meixner/saj/skript/architektursichten/examples/roodemo/pizza/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/base/list.jspx but got new mistake. Every time I launch the app and log in, I get message **This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.** The logic of the program itself was not changed. Here is new content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
     xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
     xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
     xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <spring:message code="label_singer_list"
                     var="labelSingerList"/>
    <spring:message code="label_singer_first_name"
                    var="labelSingerFirstName"/>
    <spring:message code="label_singer_last_name"
                    var="labelSingerLastName"/>
    <spring:message code="label_singer_birth_date"
                    var="labelSingerBirthDate"/>

    <h1>${labelSingerList}</h1>

    <c:if test="${not empty singers}">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>${labelSingerFirstName}</th>
                <th>${labelSingerLastName}</th>
                <th>${labelSingerBirthDate}</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${singers}" var="singer">
                <tr>
                    <td>${singer.firstName}</td>
                    <td>${singer.lastName}</td>
                    <td>${singer.birthDate}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </c:if>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't defined the singer object. If it a java class where is the import?

Comment: Singer object is created via data in my database. In fact, I have not one, but three Singer objects

Comment: http://www.hs-augsburg.de/homes/meixner/saj/skript/architektursichten/examples/roodemo/pizza/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/base/list.jspx shows an example with jspx . In my eyes you went a wrong or incomplete way to show the result.

Comment: Ok, I`ve changed my file into what you recommendet. Now I keep getting **This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it**